# Error compilling program with makefile : undefined reference to symbol 'trunc@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

Tags: compiling, libraries, makefile, mpi

I am trying to compile a program on Linux+openmpi using a makefile but got this error: I have looked at answers to similar issues but can still fix it.

```
/usr/bin/ld: outseis.o: undefined reference to symbol 'trunc@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sofi2D] Error 1
```

The makefile is below: I suspect it has to do with a missing library, but can't seems to find how to do that.

```
# Makefile for SOFI2D

#--------------------------------------------------------
# edit here:

# source code for model generation
# model file for viscoelastic modeling L>0
MODEL_V = hh_visco.c
# model file for elastic modeling L=0
MODEL_E = hh_elastic.c
# model file for viscoelastic modeling (overnight built)
MODEL_BV = benchmod.c
# model file for elastic modeling L=0 (overnight built)
MODEL_BE = benchmod_el.c
EXEC= ../bin

EXEC= ../bin


# Compiler (LAM: CC=hcc, CRAY T3E: CC=cc)

# ON Linux cluster running LAM
#CC=hcc
#LFLAGS=-lm -lmpi 
#CFLAGS=-Wall -O4

# ON Linux cluster running OpenMPI and ON MAC
CC=mpicc
LFLAGS=-lm -lmpi 
CFLAGS=-Wall -O3 

# On CRAY T3E
# CC=cc

# On SCHARnet system
#CC=mpicc
#LFLAGS=-lm  

# On HLRN system
#CC=mpcc
#LFLAGS=-lm  

# ALTIX
#CC=icc
#CFLAGS=-mp -O3 -ip0
#LFLAGS=-lmpi -lm 

# after this line, no further editing should be necessary
# --------------------------------------------------------

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

SNAPMERGE_SCR = \
    snapmerge.c \
    holbergcoeff.c\
    json_parser.c\
    merge.c \
    read_par_json.c \
    readdsk.c \
    writedsk.c \
    util.c 


SOFI2D_SRC= \
    $(MODEL_V) \
    $(MODEL_E) \
    abs_update.c \
    absorb.c \
    av_mue.c\
    av_rho.c\
    av_tau.c\
    catseis.c\
    check_fs.c\
    checkfd.c \
    comm_ini.c\
    cpml_update.c \
    exchange_par.c \
    exchange_s_rsg.c \
    exchange_s.c \
    exchange_v.c \
    sofi2D.c \
    holbergcoeff.c\
    info.c \
    initproc.c \
    json_parser.c\
    matcopy.c \
    matcopy_elastic.c \
    merge.c \
    mergemod.c \
    note.c \
    outseis.c \
    outseis_glob.c \
    operators_s.c \
    operators_v.c \
    PML_pro.c \
    prepare_update_s.c \
    prepare_update_s_4.c \
    psource.c \
    rd_sour.c \
    read_checkpoint.c\
    read_par_json.c \
    readdsk.c \
    readmod_visco.c \
    readmod_elastic.c \
    receiver.c \
    save_checkpoint.c\
    saveseis.c \
    saveseis_glob.c \
    seismo_ssg.c \
    snap_ssg.c \
    sources.c \
    splitrec.c \
    splitsrc.c \
    subgrid_bounds.c \
    surface.c \
    surface_elastic.c \
    update_s_elastic_abs.c \
    update_s_elastic_abs_4.c \
    update_s_elastic_interior.c \
    update_s_elastic_interior_4.c \
    update_s_elastic_PML.c \
    update_s_elastic_PML_4.c \
    update_s_visc_abs.c \
    update_s_visc_interior.c \
    update_s_visc_PML.c \
    update_s_visc_abs_4.c \
    update_s_visc_interior_4.c \
    update_s_visc_PML_4.c \
    update_v_abs.c \
    update_v_abs_4.c \
    update_v_interior.c \
    update_v_interior_4.c \
    update_v_PML.c \
    update_v_PML_4.c \
    util.c \
    wavefield_update_s_el.c \
    wavefield_update_s_el_4.c \
    wavefield_update_s_visc.c \
    wavefield_update_s_visc_4.c \
    wavefield_update_v.c \
    wavefield_update_v_4.c \
    wavelet.c \
    write_par.c \
    writedsk.c \
    writemod.c \
    zero_elastic.c \
    zero_elastic_4.c \
    zero_visco_4.c \
    zero_visc.c \
    zero_PML_elastic.c \
    zero_PML_visc.c 


SOFI2D_BENCH_SRC= \
    $(MODEL_BV) \
    $(MODEL_BE) \
    abs_update.c \
    absorb.c \
    av_mue.c\
    av_rho.c\
    av_tau.c\
    catseis.c\
    check_fs.c\
    checkfd.c \
    comm_ini.c\
    cpml_update.c \
    exchange_par.c \
    exchange_s_rsg.c \
    exchange_s.c \
    exchange_v.c \
    sofi2D.c \
    holbergcoeff.c\
    info.c \
    initproc.c \
    json_parser.c\
    matcopy.c \
    matcopy_elastic.c \
    merge.c \
    mergemod.c \
    note.c \
    outseis.c \
    outseis_glob.c \
    operators_s.c \
    operators_v.c \
    PML_pro.c \
    prepare_update_s.c \
    prepare_update_s_4.c \
    psource.c \
    rd_sour.c \
    read_checkpoint.c\
    read_par_json.c \
    readdsk.c \
    readmod_visco.c \
    readmod_elastic.c \
    receiver.c \
    save_checkpoint.c\
    saveseis.c \
    saveseis_glob.c \
    seismo_ssg.c \
    snap_ssg.c \
    sources.c \
    splitrec.c \
    splitsrc.c \
    subgrid_bounds.c \
    surface.c \
    surface_elastic.c \
    update_s_elastic_abs.c \
    update_s_elastic_abs_4.c \
    update_s_elastic_interior.c \
    update_s_elastic_interior_4.c \
    update_s_elastic_PML.c \
    update_s_visc_abs.c \
    update_s_visc_interior.c \
    update_s_visc_PML.c \
    update_s_elastic_PML_4.c \
    update_s_visc_abs_4.c \
    update_s_visc_interior_4.c \
    update_s_visc_PML_4.c \
    update_v_abs.c \
    update_v_abs_4.c \
    update_v_interior.c \
    update_v_interior_4.c \
    update_v_PML.c \
    update_v_PML_4.c \
    util.c \
    wavefield_update_s_el.c \
    wavefield_update_s_el_4.c \
    wavefield_update_s_visc.c \
    wavefield_update_s_visc_4.c \
    wavefield_update_v.c \
    wavefield_update_v_4.c \
    wavelet.c \
    write_par.c \
    writedsk.c \
    writemod.c \
    zero_elastic.c \
    zero_elastic_4.c \
    zero_visco_4.c \
    zero_visc.c \
    zero_PML_elastic.c \
        zero_PML_visc.c \


SNAPMERGE_OBJ = $(SNAPMERGE_SCR:%.c=%.o)

SOFI2D_OBJ = $(SOFI2D_SRC:%.c=%.o)
SOFI2D_BENCH_OBJ = $(SOFI2D_BENCH_SRC:%.c=%.o)

snapmerge:  $(SNAPMERGE_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(SNAPMERGE_OBJ) -o ../bin/snapmerge

sofi2D:     $(SOFI2D_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(SOFI2D_OBJ) -o $(EXEC)/sofi2D

sofi2D_bench:       $(SOFI2D_BENCH_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(SOFI2D_BENCH_OBJ) -o $(EXEC)/sofi2D_bench


clean:
    find . -name "*.o" -exec rm {} \; 
    find . -name "*.c%" -exec rm {} \;
    find . -name "*.bck" -exec rm {} \;

all: clean sofi2D snapmerge
```

Comment: Your makefile doesn't appear to use `LFLAGS` anywhere - where is the executable target?

Comment: @steeldriver:  i have edited the makefile and put the entire contenet

Comment: Most likely the issue is that your link rules `$(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(SNAPMERGE_OBJ) -o ../bin/snapmerge` and so on place the libraries ahead of the object files: see for example [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894098/4440445) Try re-writing those to `$(CC) -o ../bin/snapmerge $(SNAPMERGE_OBJ) $(LFLAGS)` etc.